# Search with case insensitive generating dynamic html

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search input in my HTML, and a table.

I need update the font-weight all the letters in my table, where I typed in search input, and was found in my table.

If I have a name typed like `Luke Skywalker`, and in the search input we type the letter `l`, the name will be replaced and rendered as `luke Skywalker`, i.e. with lower case.

this is my logic until now, it's clear that the behaviour will be replace the found letter for the typed in my search input, but how can I keep the capital letter, i.e, case insensitive ?

```
formatName(name) {
    if (!!this.textSearch) {
        name = name.replace(new RegExp(this.textSearch, 'gi'), `<span class='searchedText'>${this.textSearch}</span>`);
    }

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's with the double negation (`!!`)?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio It will force a boolean

Comment: You can use `name.match(new RegExp(this.textSearch, 'gi'))[0]` for example to get the first match